# How to adjust analyzer settings to allow edge_ngram to search for numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am unable to search for numbers when entering a query in elastic search on a address field, when I put in a number like "11412" it shows no result even though address with that zipcode exists.

I tried playing around with anaylzer setting changing token_chars including digits that didn't help. below is my anaylzer settings including mappings

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when using numbers in query below in elastic search I get no results, regular search with words and partial match words work though, trying to have that same behavior with numbers "11412", "1141"

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "address": {
        "query": "11412", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is because you're using the `lowercase` tokenizer which breaks tokens whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter, hence none of the digits are making it into the inverted index.

Change your `autocomplete_search` analyzer to this and it will work:

```
    "autocomplete_search": {
      "tokenizer": "standard"
    }
```